# how to add dates in php getting from database

Tags: php, sql

I have varchar datatype in database with values of dates in years and months

like below

1. 2 years, 3 months
2. 1 years ,11months
3. 0 years , 8 months

i want to add these dates and convert to Y-m-d: answer should be 4years , 10 months

how to achieve this please help
Regards

Comment: That is not a good way to store this data in the first place. You should be storing actual date values, using the appropriate data types - that makes date manipulation much easier. If you want to _display_ the dates in such a format as the described to the user, then you should only bring them in that format when you display them.

Comment: Are those years similar to time stamp? Like 1. 2 years is **2018-29-05**?

Comment: yes its similar to 2018-05

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad have you tried DAY(), YEAR(), MONTH()?

Comment: i am beginner can you please tell me in brief 

actually i'm just want to add above dates which is in string format   and shows in (Y-m) format

Comment: @MuhammadTanzeelArshad . . . You should show the data in a *tabular text* format.  Storing these values as strings doesn't make sense.  And you should show us what the data actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

```
$dates = ['2 years, 3 months', '1 years ,11months', '0 years , 8 months'];
$intervals = [];
foreach($dates as $date) {
    preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $date, $matches);
    $intervals[] = new DateInterval('P' . $matches[1][0] . 'Y' . $matches[1][1] . 'M');
}
$totalInterval = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:00', "0-0-0 0:00:00");
foreach ($intervals as $interval) {
    $totalInterval->add($interval);
}
echo ((int)$totalInterval->format("Y"). "years ," . $totalInterval->format("m") . " months");
```

Comment: Tsv your solution works like charm will you please tell me how to convert 4 years 10 months to Y-m format ?

Comment: secondly dates in 2 years, 3 months', '1 years ,11months', '0 years , 8 months save in database so i pass this to below line

$dates = [????];

Answer (score 1):

If you have two separate columns, `years` and `months`, you can add them as:

```
select sum(years) + floor(sum(months) / 12) as years,
       sum(months) - floor(sum(months) / 12) * 12 as months
from t;
```

The second expression is modulo arithmetic.  You don't specify the database, but it can probably be expressed as `sum(months) % 12` or `mod(sum(months), 12)`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp

This will answer most of your question.

`DAY(2018-29-05)` = Should get the date 29

`YEAR(2018-29-05)` = Should get the year 2018

`MONTH(2018-29-05)` = Should get the month 05

If you want to compare how many years is the difference, you can use `datediff()`

Ex. `SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '2015-29-05', '2018-29-05') AS DateDiff;`

`DateDiff` will be 3.